# how I can make a login code from the login page to the index?

Tags: javascript, php, css

I have a script for online booking and I need to make the login area from the login page to the home page like in switch over client login and agent login in one box.
The css is ready but I just need what the code I must use from the login page (first code) to put it in the home page to allow the user login, such as the third picture.

[the image http://alrayah-hotels.com/login.jpg](http://alrayah-hotels.com/login.jpg)

The code for the login page is:

```
<?php
  session_start();
  if(isset($_SESSION['password_2012']) && isset($_SESSION['agent'])){
    if($_SESSION['agent']) {
      header("location:agent_managebooking.php");
    } else {
      header("location:managebooking.php");
    }
  }

  if(isset($_POST['getpass'])) {
    include("includes/db.conn.php");
    include("includes/conf.class.php");  
    $emailid= mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email_addr']);
    $user_or_agant = $_POST['user_or_agant'];
    $bsiCore->getPassword($emailid,$user_or_agant);
  }

  if(isset($_POST['accountSelect'])) {
    include("includes/db.conn.php");
    include("includes/conf.class.php"); 
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login_email']);
    $pass  = md5(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['login_password']));

    if($_POST['accountSelect'] == 2) {
      $login = $bsiCore->loginAgent($email, $pass);
    } else {
      $login = $bsiCore->login($email, $pass);
    }


    if($login == true) {
      if($_SESSION['agent'] == 1) {
        header("location:agent_managebooking.php");
      } else {
        header("location:managebooking.php");   
      }
    } else {
      header("location:my_account.php?account=".base64_encode($_POST['accountSelect'])."&err=1");
    }
  }

  include("includes/db.conn.php");
  include("includes/conf.class.php");
  include("includes/language.php");


  if(isset($_SESSION['default_lang'])){
    $htmlCombo=$bsiCore->getbsilanguage($_SESSION['default_lang']);
  } else {
    $htmlCombo=$bsiCore->getbsilanguage(); 
  }

  global $bsiCore;

?>

<html lang="en-us" xml:lang="en-us" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head profile="http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearch/1.1/">
    <title><?=$bsiCore->config['conf_portal_name']?></title>

    <!-- Meta tags -->
    <meta http-equiv="content-language" content="en-us" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv="window-target" content="_top" />

    <!-- skip frames -->
    <meta name="robots" content="index,follow" />
    <meta name="keywords" content="booking, hotel, hotels, reservations" />
    <meta name="description" content="Online Booking" />

    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link href="img/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" />
    <link href="img/favicon.png" rel="icon" type="image/png" />

    <!-- Main Stylesheets -->
    <link href="css/style.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/extensions.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="css/print.css" media="print" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- for printing -->
    <!-- Alternate stylesheets/themes -->
    <link href="css/orange.css" media="screen" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="orange" />
    <link href="css/pink.css" media="screen" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="pink" />
    <link href="css/red.css" media="screen" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="red" />
    <link href="css/blue.css" media="screen" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="blue" />
    <link href="css/brown.css" media="screen" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="brown" />
    <link href="css/cyan.css" media="screen" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="cyan" />
    <link href="css/purple.css" media="screen" rel="alternate stylesheet" type="text/css" title="purple" />

    <!-- Your Custom Stylesheet -->
    <link href="css/custom.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <!-- RSS links (if needed) -->
    <link href="top.rss" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Top Destinations" />
    <link href="deals.rss" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Best Deals" />
    <link href="blog.rss" rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="Latest News" />

    <!-- jQuery with plugins -->
    <script src="js/jquery-1.4.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!-- Could be loaded remotely from Google CDN : <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> -->
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.core.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.widget.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.ui.tabs.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.datepick.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.datepick-en-GB.js" type="text/javascript"></script><!--  Datepick localisations: http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html -->
    <script src="js/jquery.imgpreview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.nyroModal.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.notice.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.cycle.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.notice.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Google maps and marker clustering -->
    <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?autoload={'modules':[{name:'maps',version:3,other_params:'sensor=false'}]}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/Fluster2.packed.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Custom template functions -->
    <script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/styleswitch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <!-- Internet Explorer Fixes -->
    <!--[if IE]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/ie.css"/>
    <script src="js/IE8.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
      $(document).ready(function () {
        //alert("hi");

        $("#getpassword").hide();

        $("#change_pass").click(function () {
          $("#getpassword").show();
          $("#getdetails").hide();
        });

        // Template setup
        Site.setup();

        // FAQ click handling
        $('.question > a').click(function () {
          $(this).parent().find('q').toggle();
          return false;
        });
      });
      //]]>

    </script>
  </head>

  <?php include("header.php");?>
  <!-- Left menu: Categories --> 
  <!-- End of Left menu: Categories --> 
  <!-- Questions and Answers -->
  <div class="grid_12">
    <div class="padded" style="height:425px;">
      <div id="signin_frm" align="center">
        <br />
        <?php
          if(isset($_REQUEST['err'])) {
            if(isset($_SESSION['agentmsg'])) {
              echo $_SESSION['agentmsg'];
              unset($_SESSION['agentmsg']);
            }
          }
        ?>
        <br />
        <br />
        <form name="login" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
          <div id="getdetails">
            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border:1px solid #999;"  align="center" >
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center" style="padding:10px !important;">
                  <?php
                    if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])) {
                      echo "<h3>".$_SESSION['msg']."</h3>";
                      unset($_SESSION['msg']);
                    }
                  ?>
                  <h4>
                    <?php
                      if(isset($_GET['account']) && base64_decode($_GET['account']) == 1){ echo CLIENT_LOGIN; }
                      if(isset($_GET['account']) && base64_decode($_GET['account']) == 2){ echo AGGENT_LOGIN; } ?></h4>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding:10px !important;"><?=EMMAIL_ADDRESS?></td>
                <td style="padding:10px !important;"><input type="text" name="login_email" id="login_email" title="Email Address" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding:10px !important;"><?=PASSWORD?></td>
                <td style="padding:10px !important;"><input id="login_password" class="" value="" name="login_password" type="password"/>
                  <input type="hidden" name="accountSelect" value="<?= $bsiCore->ClearInput(base64_decode($_GET['account'])) ?>" />
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td >
                  <input type="button" name="change_pass" id="change_pass" value="<?=FORGET_PASSWORD?>"  class="btn btn-custom radius" />
                </td>
                <td colspan="" style="padding:10px !important;"><input type="submit" name="Myloginbtn" id="Myloginbtn" value="<?= LOGIN_NOW ?>"  class="btn btn-custom radius" /></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div id="getpassword">
            <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border:1px solid #999;"  align="center" >
              <tr>
                <td colspan="2" align="center" style="padding:10px !important;">
                  <h4><?= GET_PASS ?></h4>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding:10px !important;"><?=EMMAIL_ADDRESS?></td>
                <td style="padding:10px !important;"><input type="text" name="email_addr" id="email_addr" title="Email Addr" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <input type="hidden" name="user_or_agant" value="<?php echo base64_decode($_GET['account']); ?>" /> 
                </td>
                <td style="padding:10px !important;"><input type="submit" name="getpass" id="getpass" value="<?=GET_PASS?>"  class="btn btn-custom radius" />
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
        </form>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- End of Questions and Answers -->
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
  </div>
  <?php include("footer.php");?>
  <!-- Scroll to top link --> 
  <a href="#" id="totop" class="radius" title="back to top"><img src="img/top.png" alt="back to top" /></a>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is what I've done but it does not work:

```
        <div id="DefaultPghdLog" class="login-container">
    <div id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_Login1_ValidationSummary1" style="color:Red;display:none;">
    </div>
    <div id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_Login1_ValidationSummary2" style="color:Red;display:none;">
    </div>
    <div id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_Login1_divRegistration">
    <div>
    <span class="login-title logInradio"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_Login1_rdRegistration" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl00$cphContent$Login1$Login" value="rdRegistration" checked="checked" onclick="javascript:ChangeControlDisplayStyle('DivPublicLogin',true,'DivAgentLogin');"><label for="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_Login1_rdRegistration">Client Login</label></span>
   </div>
    <div>
    <span class="login-title logInradio"><input id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_Login1_rdAgentLogin" type="radio" name="ctl00$ctl00$cphContent$Login1$Login" value="rdAgentLogin" onclick="javascript:ChangeControlDisplayStyle('DivAgentLogin',true,'DivPublicLogin');"><label for="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_Login1_rdAgentLogin"> Agent Login</label></span>
    </div>
    <div id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_Login1_UpdatePanel2">
            <div class="login-errormsg">
                        </div>
    </div>
     <div id="ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_Login1_pnlLogin" onkeypress="javascript:return WebForm_FireDefaultButton(event, 'ctl00_ctl00_cphContent_Login1_btnAgentLogin')">
      <div id="DivAgentLogin" class="AgentLogin" style="display: none;">
        <h2>AGENT LOGIN</h2>
      <div class="grid_12 treelogn">
     <div class="paddedf">
      <div id="signin_frm" align="center">
        <?php
        if(isset($_REQUEST['err'])){
            if(isset($_SESSION['agentmsg'])){
                echo $_SESSION['agentmsg'];
                unset($_SESSION['agentmsg']);
            }
        }
        ?>
    <form name="login" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        <div id="getdetails">
        <tr>
              <td colspan="2" align="center" style="padding:10px !important;">
              <?php if(isset($_SESSION['msg'])){
                echo "<h3>".$_SESSION['msg']."</h3>";
                unset($_SESSION['msg']);
              }
                               ?>
              <h4><?php if(isset($_GET['account']) && base64_decode($_GET['account']) == 1){ echo CLIENT_LOGIN; }if(isset($_GET['account']) && base64_decode($_GET['account']) == 2){ echo AGGENT_LOGIN; } ?></h4></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
              <td style="padding:10px !important;"><input type="text" name="login_email" id="login_email" placeholder="Email Address" title="Email Address" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td style="padding:10px !important;"><input id="login_password" class="" value="" placeholder="password" name="login_password" type="password"/>
              <input type="hidden" name="accountSelect" value="<?=$bsiCore->ClearInput(base64_decode($_GET['account']))?>" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
             <td colspan="" style="padding:10px !important;"><input type="submit" name="Myloginbtn" id="Myloginbtn" value="<?=LOGIN_NOW?>"  class="btn btn-custom radius" /></td>
               </tr>
                </div>
                    <div id="getpassword">
       <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="border:1px solid #999;"  align="center" >
            </table>
        </div>
        </form>
          <br />
      <br />
      <br />
    </div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: We are not going to read through a massive wall of badly formatted code to try and guess what/where the problem is.

Comment: i'm sorry about that,but  this is my first post here , thank you Mr.jvperrin for editing.

Comment: "The css is ready" is, by the very nature of the question, not ready: the ready css you have produces your first example (I'm guessing - you've posted the php code, not the css), while a *completely* different code will produce your desired results. What attempts at the desired css have you made?

Comment: I mean  what the code i must use from the login page to put it in the home page to allow the user login, such as the third picture. @Brian North

Answer (score 0):

If i see it right you have to use the PHP code in the start of the login page and change the part with the `if($_POST['accountSelect'] == 2) {` so it uses your radiobuttons.